# gfortran croaks with procedure pointer initially pointing to function with pointer result

Tags: fortran, function-pointers, gfortran

I'm trying to set the initial target of procedure pointer in a module as a function within the module.  When the result of the target function is a pointer, the code fails to compile with gfortran.  Note that it compiles fine with the Intel compiler.  I'm using gfortran 6.4.0.

If I remove the `pointer` attribute from the declaration of `the_proc`, then gfortran compiles it with no problem.

```
 module test_procedure_pointer
   implicit none
   private
   procedure(the_proc), pointer  :: ptr => the_proc
 contains    
   function the_proc()
     integer, pointer :: the_proc
   end function the_proc
 end module test_procedure_pointer
```

The error is:

```
% gfortran -c procpointer.f90  

procpointer.f90:4:50:

procedure(the_proc), pointer  :: ptr => the_proc  
                                   1  
**Error**: Pointer initialization target at (1) must have the TARGET attribute
```

gfortran version:

```
% gfortran --version  
GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.4.0  
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO  
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Likely a bug in the compiler. Try tge current versiin. If not fixed there, report to GCC.

Comment: I reported it on the GNU bug report page.  Here's the link: [Bug ID 84504](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84504)

Comment: Nice, if they confirm the bug or give you other explanation you can answer your question here with the result.